# Convert column to rownames in a dataframe without prepending X

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to convert the numerical values in a column of an existing data frame into row names. Is it possible to do this without prepending an X to the row names?

Example dataframe:

```
df1 = data.frame(names=c(111,20,32,45),
                 var=c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3","Gene4"))
```

To:

```
df2 = df1

rownames(df2) = make.names(df2$names, unique=TRUE)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble` which also drops the column which was converted to rownames, i.e.

```
library(tibble)

column_to_rownames(df1, var = 'names')
#      var
#111 Gene1
#20  Gene2
#32  Gene3
#45  Gene4
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting error: `Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`

Comment: I figured there was an `NA` in the `names` column. NA removed, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
rownames(df2) = df2$names
```

But, if you have duplicate names and you want to remove the duplicates first, you need to do the following:

```
df2 = df2[!duplicated(df2$names),]
rownames(df2) = df2$names
```

Hope it helps.